# Why Is Scalar Multiply Before Einsum Faster?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensorflow-xla

In the TensorFlow Keras [implementation of Multi-Head Attention](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f9336cc5114b4a9429a242deb264b707379646b7/keras/layers/attention/multi_head_attention.py#L520), instead of evaluating the numerator first like in

[image]

they evaluate Q/√dₖ first and put comment

> Note: Applying scalar multiply at the smaller end of einsum improves
> XLA performance, but may introduce slight numeric differences in
> the Transformer attention head.

How is it faster this way? Wouldn't the division after einsum be equally as fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the comment suggest is that the the number of elements in `key` is less than the number of elements in `query` or `attention_scores` in the following equation.

```
attention_scores = tf.einsum(self._dot_product_equation, key, query)
```

Given the dimensions

```
            query: Projected query `Tensor` of shape `(B, T, N, key_dim)`.
            key: Projected key `Tensor` of shape `(B, S, N, key_dim)`.
```

Assuming that `_dot_product_equation` is simply doing the batched matrix multiplication, if Q is `T x N`, and Q is `S x N`, the product `Q @ K.T` is `T x S`, if `S > N` the number of multiplications is expected to be smaller on the left.

But either way that should not be the dominant part except if `S > T * N` (or XLA has a bug).

Comment: So query x key ends up with [B, T, N, S] and if T and S are the lengths of a long text input, then that ends up being a large tensor. Then dividing Q is faster since it is a smaller tensor. They're betting on key_dim being smaller than T and S for most cases? Is my reasoning correct and is this not only specific to XLA?

Comment: Exacltly, but this scalar multiplication should not dominate the run time, (1) softmax requires computing an elementwise exponential and a division in the long side, (2) presumably the matrix multiplication takes does N multiplication for each entry in the long side. Another possible reason is that the product is being done in the CPU and the broadcasting requires replicating the values in the GPU memory a number of times proportional to the size of the other operand, that could cause this operation to dominate the run time.